# Filtering and redirecting in a django view not performing as expected

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a very simple view that checks to see if something exists and then redirects if it doesn't. For some reason it doesn't work. The exception keeps firing. I have verified that there are records in the DB that should be returning.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
@login_required
def goal_display(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)

    if request.user != user:
        return permission_denied(request)

    try:
        goal = Goal.objects.filter(user=user).latest('created')

        return render_to_response('achieve/dashboard.html', {
                "goal": goal
                }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except:
        return redirect('goal_add')
```

Comment: does `Goal` have `created` and `user` fields ?

Comment: What exception? A bare `except` is rarely a good idea, try to change it to `except Goal.DoesNotExist` and see if you get another error (please post full traceback if this is the case)

Comment: That's so weird. When I added you suggestion everything started working.  That is really strange.

Comment: Funny :) If you change it back, is it broken again?

Comment: No, so now I'm really confused. One last question. Why Goal and not goal. How does the try know to look for the Goal?

Comment: The `try` block only knows it should catch exceptions of a specific kind, in this case, `Goal.DoesNotExist`. Every Django model has its own `DoesNotExist` exception class, so `except Goal.DoesNotExist` catches _all_ `DoesNotExist` exceptions relating to `Goal`. The variable `goal` doesn't have anything to do with it; it is not even set yet when the exception is raised inside `.latest()`

Comment: The 'ghost' error might have something to do with your browser caching the redirect; you might want to limit/disable caching for views like that (for example using the decorator [`django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers))

Comment: Knowing when an apache restart is required and when it is not, is very subtle with Django.  I make it a habit to restart Apache (or django server if that's what server you're using here) after almost any change, before testing (obviously in dev environment, hopefully you're not doing code changes in production).  You can end up with old versions of code resurfacing oddly if you don't do this, in a way I find difficult to predict, and your ghost error might have been that.

Comment: Your call to get_object_or_404 for User is completely pointless. `request.user` is **already** the User object. You are querying again for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you try with a if statement and exists()? I think is easier.

```
def goal_display(request):
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)

if request.user != user:
    return permission_denied(request)

if(Goal.objects.filter(user=user).lastest('created').exists()):
    goal = Goal.objects.filter(user=user).latest('created')

    return render_to_response('achieve/dashboard.html', {
            "goal": goal
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return redirect('goal_add')
```

Maybe is not the prettiest way but i think it should work.